# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone()

Tags: maven, junit, pom.xml, java-17

After migrating to Java 17 from Java 8  and while running the test cases , the test case is failed with
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected native java.lang.Object java.lang.Object.clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module .

this fails while using Whitebox.invokeMethod in the test cases.

maven-version - 3.8.1
junit-jupiter-engine version - 5.8.2

Anything with respect to version change mismatch Java 17 will cause this kind of issue?

Comment: Probably due to your lib is using java internal class/api, which is blocked in jdk17. But need your test class(best to be executable) to see how to resolve.

Comment: Instead of overriding access to `Object.clone()`, you should acquire a method handle to the `clone()` method of the specific class that supports cloning.